# Using UIImagePickerController to take video and picker'view not full-screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to take video in my app running iOS7, then I use UIImagePickerController to do it. But I find the picker's view not full-screen, appears 2 black view both on left and right? How to resize for full-screen. Code like this:

```
  picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
  picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720;
```

I tried to set videoQuality with UIImagePickerControllerQualityType640x480, then appears 2 black view both on top and bottom.

And when present picker(on iOS7), how to change status bar style? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGSize screenSize       = CGSizeMake(320, 708);
float cameraAspectRatio = 4.0 / 3.0;
float imageWidth        = floorf(screenSize.width * cameraAspectRatio);
float scale             = ceilf((screenSize.height / imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0;
myImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform   = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pickerViewcontroller Delegate to customer it,for example

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIImagePickerController * picker  = (UIImagePickerController *) navigationController;
    if (picker.sourceType != UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        [viewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"请选择照片"];
        viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = ....
        viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  ...     
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Customs picker view's frame?